# GuzzleHttp\Client JSON Return as String

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I have very simple question, how to convert this strings to JSON ?

This string i am getting from Guzzle POST Request and here is code :

```
return $body->getBody()->getContents();
```

Result:

```
""k\n\n{\"success\":true,\"payload\":{\"id\":\"txn_ngS2aS9FY7raxy8JTUivAZCtWJy7EeznwPE8\"}}""
```

with var_dump result and what is that k before ?

```
string(79) "k {"success":true,"payload":{"id":"txn_eeM6T6Fvkq3Pr4AWtK2TKYmNwKmodNwVqJod"}}"
```

Comment: You're json_encoding it twice.

Answer (score 1):

The string is already `json_encode`d, you should simply return the `$body->getBody()->getContents()`.

Comment: Yes i tried that but then it giving me null as result.

Comment: What happens when you var_dump the contents?

Comment: That return big NULL :), i have never seen problem like this, if return simple body content then result is string and when decode then return null.

Comment: You might wanna try the `read` method as well, but then you have to specify the number of bytes you want to read.

Comment: Yeah, the `k` is pretty weird and that why your JSON functions are returning null.

Comment: You can simply decode it after trimming the `k`, but it being there makes no sense in the first place. Would you mind me asking which URL you're making the request? Is it an external API?

Comment: Its about the response content and the payload i guess.

Comment: Yes trying to figure out, but that k cause problem and i think it's random as before when i was calling this was working fine.

Comment: Good luck with the `k`, sadly have no idea about that. :(

Comment: Thanks for your help i fixed that by regex and only picking content that comes with and after {

Comment: Great idea, I'm glad you dealt with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found problem isn't in my code but it was in external api payload, payload sending json data with `"k"` string.

Thanks @Ozan Kurt to figure out external link.

So right now only picking curly brackets with regex :

```
$result = preg_match("/{.+}", $body->getBody()->getContents(), $matched);

if ($matched) {
  return json_decode($matched[0]);
}
```